# l informe de 'Esquema XML' es 'Falta el elemento ra¡z.'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, webservice, asp.net-web-api

tardes o noches..

Estoy haciendo una practica de WS SOAP, pero después de crear mi directorio raíz me dice que no contiene dicho elemento, me aparece un mensaje cuando yo lo ejecuto, adjunto proyecto, espero y me ayuden a resolverlo.

```
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OumXjertb8UAF2-lfEoOXGkHVVgi08ST
```

Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from http://localhost/WcfServiceCliente/ClienteService.svc If this is a Windows (R) Communication Foundation service to which you have access, please check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified address.  For help enabling metadata publishing, please refer to the MSDN documentation at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.WS-Metadata Exchange Error    URI: http://localhost/WcfServiceCliente/ClienteService.svc    Los metadatos contienen una referencia que no se puede resolver: 'http://localhost/WcfServiceCliente/ClienteService.svc'.    El servidor no proporcion¢ una respuesta significativa; la causa puede ser un contrato que no coincide, el apagado prematuro de una sesi¢n o un error interno del servidor.HTTP GET Error    URI: http://localhost/WcfServiceCliente/ClienteService.svc    El documento en la direcci¢n URL http://localhost/WcfServiceCliente/ClienteService.svc no se reconoce como un tipo de documento conocido.El mensaje de error de los tipos de documento conocidos puede ayudarle a resolver el problema:- El informe de 'Esquema XML' es 'Falta el elemento ra¡z.'.- El informe de 'Documento DISCO' es 'Falta el elemento ra¡z.'.- El informe de 'Documento WSDL' es 'Error en el documento XML (0, 0).'.  - Falta el elemento ra¡z.

**si bajan el proyecto ejecuten el visual studio como administrador**

Answer (score 0):

Bueno para lo que tengan este problema basta con habilitar para poder utilizar dichos protocolos http y net.tcp.

adjunto respuesta encontrada...

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/enable-other-protocols-tcp-pipe-msmq-etc-in-iis/

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]